# big size file upload on web azure with slow internet

Tags: c#, azure-storage

I have to store file uploaded on my website on azure storage. If internet connection is slow and I am directly calling blob then it is taking huge time to upload due to slow connection between my server and user. How should I do it so that it can work fine and user experience will not get effected?

Comment: you can get it done block wise what we call it as small chunks.. though it will ensure data integrity but cant say anything about time frame. As large file will always take time to upload on slow connections.

Comment: Can I use some queue or something?

Comment: yes you have a facility to use Queue in that, check this link : http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/